# Range.AutoFilter only using last criteria? VBA

Tags: vba, autofilter

I have a table that I want to move elsewhere, and I want to delete a good portion of the data (there are quite a few blanks or 0's I don't really care about). Here is what I have for the code so far:

```
Dim srcRange As Range
Dim copysheet As Worksheet

Set copysheet = ActiveSheet

Set srcRange = copysheet.range("B1:D1598")
srcRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("#VALUE!", "Count", 0, Empty)
srcRange.Delete
```

With this setup it only deletes the blanks, so I tested it a few times with the following variations:

```
'this code will return only the 0's
Dim srcRange As Range
Dim copysheet As Worksheet

Set copysheet = ActiveSheet

Set srcRange = copysheet.range("B1:D1598")
srcRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("#VALUE!", "Count", 0)

'this code will return only the "count"'s
Dim srcRange As Range
Dim copysheet As Worksheet

Set copysheet = ActiveSheet

Set srcRange = copysheet.range("B1:D1598")
srcRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("#VALUE!", "Count")
```

So the conclusion I have come to is that for some reason the AutoFilter tool is only filtering by the last criteria I put into criteria1. Anyone able to give me some insight as to why?

FYI- my temporary work around is to run 4 filter/delete commands instead of one and it is working alright- I just would like to learn a bit as to what causes this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need need to add `Operator:=xlFilterValues` to your AutoFilter call:

```
srcRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("#VALUE!", "Count"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

This will filter for all elements provided in Criteria1

Comment: Question is old as hell, but I desperately need help. The solution you've posted raises `run-time error 1004 autofilter method of range class failed`

Comment: did you check that your srcRange is a valid range that contains the whole table?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, I've tryed using UsedRange(table is the only content of the sheet anyway), CurrentRegion of table's top left cell(`.Range("A5").CurrentRegion`), manualy appointed range (`.Range("A5","E25")`) and as the last resort tryed using `Selection`